# Not able to insert data into excel sheet using PhpExcel

Tags: phpexcel

I'm trying to open an excel sheet and insert few records into it. But, it's not working. 
Here is my code

```
            $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
            //we load the file that we want to read
            $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("/home/bigc/Desktop/test.xlsx");
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

            // Change the file
            $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
                        ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
                        ->setCellValue('B1', 'World!');

            // Write the file               
            $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            ini_set('display_errors', 1);
            $objWriter->save("/home/bigc/Documents/test.xlsx");

            //we save
            $objWriter->save();
```

The error which it throws is

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Writer_Exception' with message 'Could not close zip file /home/bigc/Documents/test.xlsx.' in /home/bigc/Development/Development/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php:399 Stack trace: #0 /home/bigc/Development/Development/Upload.php(39): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007->save('/home/bigc/Docu...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/bigc/Development/Development/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php on line 399

I've already set read & write  permissions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only three causes for this error are invalid filepath, permissions, or that the file is already open/locked by a different process.... PHP safe_mode or base_dir can restrict access to a filepath with otherwise valid permissions, as can the suhosin patch

Comment: Hi @MarkBaker, I've checked file permissions. I've set them to read and write, and the file is not already opened & when I click on the path from aptana studio, it takes me to the file. So, it means the file exists & moreover why does it show me "Could not close zip file"??

Comment: I have absolutely no idea whatsoever, you've clearly found a fourth circumstance that can cause this problem; but unless that cause can be isolated then I can't do anything at all to help

Answer (score 0):

But that is the issue, you are trying to write over the top of the file on your desk top. It is not an issue with your code or phpexcel. It is about permissions. Try saving the file to a different location, then to the same location but with a different name. Is the current file read only by chance. Keep chasing the permission issue.

Comment: I've changed to destination file too. Then what's the reason for loading the desktop file? I've put the file in $objWriter->save("/home/bigc/Documents/test.xlsx");.. Still the same thing with different location.. I've updated the error. Please check it.

Comment: To aid with problem determination, I would add these two lines to the top of your program "file_put_contents('/home/bigc/Documents/test.xlsx','test file');" and "unlink('/home/bigc/Documents/test.xlsx');" if those two lines work and you get to the phpexcel code, then we can debug Mark's code.  If you never get that far, then it points to a system administration issue, not a problem with phpexcel or your program.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Those two lines work. 'test file' is getting added to the excel sheet. But, not the code which I've put in there.

Comment: It seems like it only partially worked. The first line worked. You run your script and you are left with a file named test.xlsx with a content of "Test File". So far so good, we are getting some where.  But the second line of code was supposed to delete that very file.  From what you said, it was not deleted.  That points to some kind of a permission issue where you can create a file, but not delete it. That would have nothing to do with phpexcel.

Comment: Your sample code has two ->save() one with a file name, that you are getting an error on and another one following that. The second one should not be there. This has nothing to do with your issue but thought I would point it out.

Comment: Given that your error was on the zip, lets try using 2005 instead of 2007, just to see if that makes a difference. If you have the same issue, it points to file permissions. If it works, then it points to something in the 2007 code. try this. // Write the file error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); $objWriter=PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel,'Excel5'); $objWriter->save("/home/bigc/Documents/test.xls");